# Boolean not setting in constructor

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a button that toggles a boolean on/off when it is pressed. I am already using a similar format for toggling other modules on/off, and it works perfectly. However, for some reason unbeknown to me, the boolean I am trying to assign the variable to never toggles at all.

Here is the code that creates the boolean:

```
boolean rainbow = false; 
panels.add(new Panel("Hub", 50, 50, false) {
            public void loadElements() {
                getElements().add(new ElementBoolean("Rainbow", rainbow));
            }
        });
```

And here is the box class, which gets the boolean variable, and is supposed to toggle it on/off.

```
private String label;
private boolean property;

public ElementBoolean(String label, boolean property) {
    super(label);
    this.label = label;
    this.property = property;
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(int mX, int mY, int button)
{
    switch(button) {
        case 0: {
            if(!isSelected(mX, mY)) return;
            this.property = !this.property;

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Again, this format works fine for handling other modules, but for toggling the boolean is never assigns 'property' to the boolean 'rainbow' as it is supposed to. Therefore, the boolean 'property' is toggled correctly, however the variable 'rainbow' stays false. I'm sorry if I am missing something extremely simple, I just cannot understand why this isn't working.

No stack trace because it doesn't generate any errors.

Comment: There's some good further reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Does making it `final boolean rainbow` change anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that primitives (e.g. boolean) are passed by value, means that when you are passing rainbow to ElementBoolean's constructor, Java creates a new local variable in stack which is not referenced anyhow with initial rainbow variable.
What you actually need is a Mutable (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/mutable/package-summary.html)
If you don't want to use Apache library you can implement it easily by yourself:

```
public class Mutable<T> {

  private T value;

  public Mutable(final T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public T get() {
    return this.value;
  }

  public void set(final T value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, I switched to MutableBoolean instead of boolean and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand you, everything you posted here seems alright, but I have a feeling you are trying to do something like this:

```java
boolean rainbow = false; 
panels.add(new Panel("Hub", 50, 50, false) {
  public void loadElements() {
    getElements().add(new ElementBoolean("Rainbow", rainbow));
  }
});

//now you click mouse
//and now you expect variable rainbow to be true after mouse clicked
if(rainbow == true)
  doSomething();
```

Point is you are not changing the variable `rainbow`, you are changing the variable `property` in `ElementBoolean` object instance. What you need to do is (before you try to use rainbow):

`rainbow = yourElementBooleanInstance.getProperty()`

Ofcourse, since it's `private` you need to make a `getProperty()` method returning `property` value and somehow save the instance of `ElementBoolean`, because you are not doing this right now (you can also make field `property` and `getProperty()` static and then do `ElementBoolean.getProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

See the following two calls:

```
f(x)
new ElementBoolean("Rainbow", rainbow)
```

The passed variable (`x` and `rainbow`) will in java never be overwritten with another value. You allways **pass-by-value**. The field `property` is not an *alias* of `rainbow`.

This was an intentional design decision, as you now know:

```
String s = "happy";
p(s);
// s still will be "happy", not null or whatever
```